# uptade nested array with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update the value of an object using **$ set** to pass an **Object** into a nested array element, however the element tha is updated is the first element not the one I query. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Schema

```
const storySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //some fields
    stages: [{
        //some fields
        events: [{
            author: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User',
                required: true
            },
            body: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            }     
        }]
    }]
})
```

The update route in express

```
  Story.findOneAndUpdate({ 'stages.events._id': req.params.eventId }, {
    '$set': {
      'stages.0.events.$': req.body.event
    }
  }, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true
  })
```

Comment: Use `arrayFilters`. Something like `Story.findOneAndUpdate({ 'stages.events._id': req.params.eventId }, {
    '$set': {
      'stages.0.events.$[event]': req.body.event
    }
  }, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'event._id': req.params.eventId }]
  }`

Comment: @Veeram, thanks your suggestion worked perfectly. I just had to make a small change and parse the envetId to ObjectID in the arrayFilters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @Veeram suggestion, I used arrayFilters in the solution.

Here is the solution.

```
  Story.findOneAndUpdate({ 'stages.events._id': req.params.eventId }, {
    '$set': {
      'stages.0.events.$[event]': req.body.event
    }
  }, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
    arrayFilters: [{ 'event._id': mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.params.eventId) }]
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 Story.findOneAndUpdate({ 'stages.events._id': req.params.eventId }, {
    '$set': {
      'stages.$.events.$': req.body.event
    }
  }, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true
  })
```